# What is wrong with this batch alias using python3

Tags: python-3.x, alias

What I'm doing wrong in this batch alias:

> alias youtube-dl=python3 /usr/local/bin/youtube-dl

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to wrap the python command in single quotes:

```
alias youtube-dl = 'python3 /usr/local/bin/youtube-dl'
```